# Disable new blockquote contenteditable

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable

Disable new blockquote if Enter keypress on COntentent editable
javascript or jQuery

**HTML**

```
<div id="demo" contenteditable="true">
   <p>This is a paragraph. Lorem Ipsum...</p>
   <blockquote>This is a blockquote. Enter here</blockquote>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
blockquote {
    background: beige;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px dashed #dadada;
}
```

**Snippet**

```css
blockquote {
    background: beige;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px dashed #dadada;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo" contenteditable="true">
  <p>This is a paragraph. Lorem Ipsum...</p>
  <blockquote>This is a blockquote. Enter here</blockquote>
</div>
```

Comment: Unclear on what you want to achieve. Please explain your question.

Comment: Look at this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552336/prevent-contenteditable-adding-div-on-enter-chrome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ans based on [This old so ans.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14667764/in-contenteditable-how-do-you-add-a-paragraph-after-blockquote-on-enter-key-pres). Slightly modified for ans.

```js
$('#demo').keypress(function(e) {
  var key = e.which;
  if (key == 13) // the enter key code
  {
    var input = document.getElementById('demo');

    if (whichTag("blockquote")) {

      document.execCommand('InsertParagraph');
      document.execCommand('Outdent');

    }
  }
});

function whichTag(tagName) {

  var sel, containerNode;
  var tagFound = false;

  tagName = tagName.toUpperCase();

  if (window.getSelection) {

    sel = window.getSelection();

    if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {
      containerNode = sel.getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer;
    }

  } else if ((sel = document.selection) && sel.type != "Control") {

    containerNode = sel.createRange().parentElement();

  }

  while (containerNode) {

    if (containerNode.nodeType == 1 && containerNode.tagName == tagName) {

      tagFound = true;
      containerNode = null;

    } else {

      containerNode = containerNode.parentNode;

    }

  }

  return tagFound;
}
```

```css
blockquote {
  background: beige;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px dashed #dadada;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo" contenteditable="true">
  <p>This is a paragraph. Lorem Ipsum...</p>
  <blockquote>This is a blockquote. Enter here</blockquote>
</div>
```