# Contenteditable, blockquote inner default tag

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

Defaultly by typing some content inside my editor I get this value:
`<p>some text</p>`. Unfortunately when I use `document.exec('formatBlock, false, 'blockquote')` on typed value the result is:

```
<blockquote>some text</blockquote>
```

Because of that when I click enter instead of expanding current blockquote I get a new one.

How to add a value to a blockquote and then format the value by 'p' tag? Or how to already add to blockquote formatted value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable new blockquote contenteditable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44258572/disable-new-blockquote-contenteditable)